# Whats the quickest way to check if an array of dicts all equate to false?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For instance, given the following array of dicts:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

I would like to test whether there are any non-empty dicts and return True if so, e.g.:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] == False
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {'key': 'val'}] == True
```

Comment: By _"array of objects"_ you imply that there might be objects that aren't dictionaries in your list. Should this read _"list of dictionaries"_?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function.

```
>>> any([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}])
False
>>> any([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {'key': 'val'}])
True
```

The `any` function iterates through an iterable and checks if any of the values are `True`-ish. These values are any value not included below:

```
False
0  # and any value equal to it, e.g. 0.0
None
[]
()
# and any other empty container
```

The `{}` is an empty container (dictionary), and so evaluates to `False` in a boolean context. When you include a non-empty dictionary into the list, the result is `True`, because there is now a value in the list which evaluates to `True` in a boolean context.